# CbBackup Tool gets interrupted after 30s of inactivity for specific buckets in a cluster

Tags: couchbase

I have a cluster with 4 buckets in it. Whenever I try to take backups for the buckets individually, two of the buckets get backed up while the other two do not get backed up.

For the buckets which do not get backed up, I got this message in the console.

```
w0 no response for 30 seconds while there 1024 active streams
```

This is the command I’m running for each bucket.

```
./cbbackup http://localhost:8091 /datadrive/cb-backups/ -u <USERNAME> -p '<PASSWORD>' -b <BUCKET_NAME> -m full
```

These are the specs for those two buckets which were not getting backed up.

```
Bucket 1 - 4GB RAM, currently has around 400,000 documents.
Bucket 2 - 4GB RAM, currently has around 150,000 documents.
```

It’s worth noting that we first had 2GB ram in both the buckets. After increasing the RAM for both the buckets, backups started working again but the same error occured from the next day

Is there an inherent problem with the CbBackup tool? Does anyone know how the backups are actually taken? That would give more insight into why this error might occur.

```
DISTILLED TECHNICAL INFORMATION:

Couchbase Server - Community Edition 5.0.1 build 5003
Command used - `./cbbackup http://localhost:8091 /datadrive/cb-backups/ -u <USERNAME> -p '<PASSWORD>' -b <BUCKET_NAME> -m full`

* Bucket Specs -
   * Bucket 1 - 4GB RAM, currently has around 400,000 documents.
   * Bucket 2 - 4GB RAM, currently has around 150,000 documents.
```

Thanks for your valuable time.